Can we construct the exterior algebra just from simple multivectors?
$
\newcommand\K{\mathbb K}
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\Lip{\mathrm{Lip}}
\newcommand\ev{\mathrm{ev}}
\newcommand\Gr{\mathrm{Gr}}
$Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\K$-vector space and $\Ext V$ its exterior algebra. The Lipschitz monoid $\Lip(V)$ is the monoid of all simple multivectors, or equivalently the monoid of all multiples of exterior products of vectors:
$$
  \Lip(V) = \{\alpha v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k \;:\; \alpha\in\K,\; v_1,\dotsc,v_k \in V,\: k \geq 0\}.
$$
Can we construct $\Ext V$ from $\Lip(V)$?
$\Ext V$ "feels" quite like the monoid algebra $\K[\Lip(V)]$ of $\Lip(V)$ but modulo the vector space structure of $V$. Indeed, note that $V \subseteq \Lip(V)$. Denoting the scalar product of $\K[\Lip(V)]$ by $\cdot$, the set
$$
  \K\cdot V = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i\cdot v_i \;:\; \alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_k\in\K,\: v_1,\dotsc,v_k\in V,\: k\geq 0\right\} \subseteq \Lip(V)
$$
of all formal linear combinations of vectors has a natural evaluation map $\ev : \K\cdot V \to V$ taking formal linear combinations to actual linear combinations; in symbols,
$$
  \ev\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i\cdot v_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_iv_i.
$$
This map easily extends to a homomorphism $\K[\Lip(V)] \to \Ext V$. First, for any $\alpha \in \K$ and $X \in \Lip(V)$, define
$$
  \ev(\alpha\cdot X) = \alpha X
$$
which suffices to define $\ev$ on all of $\K[\Lip(V)] = \bigoplus_{X\in\Lip(V)}\K\cdot X$. Now we check that it is as homomorphism: if $\beta \in \K$ and $Y \in \Lip(V)$ then
$$
  \ev([\alpha\cdot X][\beta\cdot Y]) = \ev([\alpha\beta]\cdot[X\wedge Y]) = \alpha\beta X\wedge Y,
$$$$
  \ev(\alpha\cdot X)\wedge\ev(\beta\cdot Y) = (\alpha X)\wedge(\beta Y) = \alpha\beta X\wedge Y,
$$
so $\ev$ is indeed a homomorphism.
This gives $\Ext V \cong \K[\Lip(V)]/\ker(\ev)$ as vector spaces.
The above suggests to me that, perhaps, there is some universal property that allows us to generate $\Ext V$ from $\Lip(V)$; but it is not clear to me what exactly this universal property is, nor what category it should take place in.
This is just the approach that I first thought up; if anyone has a completely different way of deriving $\Ext V$ from $\Lip(V)$ that would be most appreciated.
This question could be extended to Clifford algebras in general, but I think there is some more subtlety in the general case which I think makes it best to leave that to a future question.

As for why I am interested in doing this:
Consider the following relation on $\Lip(V)$:
$$
  X \sim Y \iff \exists\alpha\in\K\setminus\{0\}.\: X = \alpha Y.
$$
This relation is compatible with the monoid structure of $\Lip(V)$, so $\Lip(V)/{\sim}$ is a monoid; denote the equivalence classes of this quotient by $[{-}]$. But we have a bijection
$$
  \begin{gathered}
    (\Lip(V)/{\sim})\setminus\{[0]\} 
  \\
    [X]
  \end{gathered}
  \mathrel{\begin{gathered}
    \longleftrightarrow
  \\
    \longmapsto
  \end{gathered}}
  \begin{gathered}
    \Gr(V), \\ \{v \in V \;:\; v\wedge X = 0\}.
  \end{gathered}
$$
where $\Gr(V)$ is the Grassmannian of $V$.
This makes $\Gr(V)\sqcup\{\mathbf0\}$ into a monoid (where $\mathbf0$ is a formal zero) and shows how we can construct $\Lip(V)/{\sim}$ geometrically. It's worth describing this product in terms of $\Gr(V)$: for any $S, T \in \Gr(V)$ it is defined by
$$
  S\wedge T = \begin{cases}
    \mathbf0 &\text{if }S\cap T\ne\{0\}, \\
    \mathrm{span}(S\cup T) &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$
and by requiring $\mathbf0$ to be a zero element. Note that $\{0\}$ is the identity. Put another way, this product is just the internal direct sum of subspaces returning the sigil $\mathbf0$ when such a direct sum is invalid.
We could then go from here to $\Lip(V)$ and then to $\Ext V$, giving a very geometric construction $\Ext V$. It's unclear to me how to identify $V$ as a subset of $\Lip(V)$ from this construction, but I will leave that for another question.

Does Lip$(V)$ include all scalars, or just the scalar $1$ (and $0$)?

Good catch. I guess the two definitions I gave aren't equivalent. I think, morally for this specific question, I want it to include all scalars: just like all (nonzero) multiples of a vector or bivector represent a line or plane, all multiples of $1$ represent the origin. This is also how Micali and Helmstetter define it in Quadratic Mappings and Clifford algebras (see proposition 5.3.2); it seems that one of their goals in defining $\mathrm{Lip}(V)$ is for it to contain all bivector exponentials.
